# I created a resource for an answer. Are there specifications/rules to include it as picture or link?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, answers

I answered to this question "[Looking up gnuplot abbreviations](https://superuser.com/q/508644/257269)", in the beginning giving only the method to find the meaning of the abbreviations used or usable.

After I've created a a resource (a document, the list of abbreviation for a specific version), because it was difficult to find it online, I couldn't, and however uneasy to generate for windows user.

I preferred to post as `pdf` file but I finish to convert in `png` with good definition 600 DPI,  ready to be printed.

Double side of the question:

1. Is it in general too heavy a 600 DPI (single page document) to post ?
2. Should I **post only the link**, in order to make more light the page to be loaded, or can I post it as pdf file (in this case how)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be tempted to post it as text, using the code sample option, for searchability

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There are a couple of fixes to put  by hand (I didn't have time to see exactly how to fix. BTW I can but is a long list (349 lines - 4394 charachters) ... maybe not so long...  How to put with some HTML code in the page or as plain text?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Done with a corrected list with `\` .. \` `. But it remains the question in general...

Comment: Pre tags - I've used them for inserting ASCII diagrams in the past

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Perfect. Thanks again. `*** DONE ***`.

Comment: @Hastur It would be even better if you **sorted** the list ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Maybe you're right. (_Pro_ and _contra_). Some are commands, some are options. The options are grouped per command that can accept them... (in the code for `struct`...)... Ok from the text  answer even under windows it shouldn't be so difficult to sort them `;-D`. Are you suggesting to add the png of the ordered list too? ... and I was worrying that it was too heavy a png... :D

Comment: @DavidPostill I think about it, and I decide you're right. I put the ordered version and a link to the non ordered one. (ps> so no rules/indication about it, just the 2MB of the upload?)